# What happens when I rate a Steam Review funny?

Tags: steam

When I see a funny review and I click on "Funny"...

[image: A funny Steam review]

...apart from the text "x people found this review funny" changing, is there anything that happens behind the scenes, making this review ranked higher or lower?

Comment: I feel so lost on the joke here

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Saying that a review is funny does not do anything besides increase the counter saying "people found this review funny".

Answer (score 11):

Just to expand on the (correct) accepted answer, the 'funny' button was added to try to curb the number of joke reviews that would get upvoted to the top of the list despite not actually being helpful.  This gives you a way to give the reviewer some kudos without necessarily saying the review is helpful in figuring out if someone would like the game or not (though you can also mark reviews both as helpful *and* funny).